# Which route matches a fixed controller with variable action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this controller called activities, which contains methods, such as updateweight, displaycalories, etc.

```
<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Home", "/" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Update Weight", "/activities/upweight" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Food Ressources", "/activities/food_res" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Exercises Technics", "/activities/exercises" %></li>
</ul>
```

Which route would be able to get to the **activities controller** and to the method with the name that comes after? I've tried ressources :activities, but I'm getting bizarre results.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling any arbitrary action in a controller is non-RESTful. Much older rails versions handled this like:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

.. and in fact that's still possible with Rails today. You should be careful not to mix RESTful and arbitrary actions in a single controller since actions like 'create' and 'delete' should not respond to GET requests.

Alternatively you could promote 'weight', 'foods' and 'exercises' to their own resources.

Also, you apparently can't spell 'resources' or 'techniques' though I rather like the image of exercising one's technics.

Answer (score 2):

To find the available routes, utilize the command `rake routes` from command line of your rails app directory.  This will show you a list of the potential routes you can use as links. They will typically look like:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
```

etc...

In your case though, you are making non-default url's, so you need to add them to your `config/routes.rb` file. So for example add:

```
get '/activities/upweight' => 'activities#upweight'
```

This would connect the chosen url to the correct controller#action you desire using a GET http request.

Also note, if you've created your routes for the activities controller in `routes.rb` using the line `resources :activities`, then you need to make sure to add the custom routing line *above* this. `resources :activities` serves as a catch-all for custom urls, and will route them to the controller's show method.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the route can look like these:

```
match "/activities/upweight", :as => "activities#upweight" 
match "/activities/food_res", :as => "activities#food_res" 
match "/activities/exercises", :as => "activities#exercises"
```

Provided that you have method named as `upweight`, `food_res`, `exercises`